# Custom celery settings file for django-celery

Tags: django, settings, celery

Django-celery seems to use the current django project's settings.py file to read the configuration for celery, and, correct me if I am wrong, there is no way to override this behavior. The problem is that my celery configuration is in a different file outside of the django project, and I need to somehow tell django-celery to use that file instead. How do I do this?

Comment: As a temporary solution I am simply importing the celery configuration file in the django settings.py 
"from /otherproject/celerysetttings.py import *"

Answer (score 0):

Generally, django-celery used for one project(but many applications). Of course, you can make symlink of the settings.py from one project to other and run Django-celery as:

> ./manage.py celeryd --settings=path.to.symlink

but in my opinion would be better decision to use celery as daemon with common settings and `CELERY_IMPORTS` to tasks from any django projects